# Show subcategories as grid magento

Tags: php, magento

I tried to do this on my site: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html

All steps got done correctly but nothing is showing on my site. My main site is inside /app/design/frontend/NAME/default/ ....

Is there something I have to change on the code given on that site? Or if you have any better idea to make this work.

Thank you